# Pandas - Create new column and assign values based on filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe

```
id  category
1   A        
2   A
3   B
4   C
5   A
```

And I want to create a new column with incremental values where `category == 'A'`. So it should be something like.

```
id  category  value
1   A         1
2   A         2
3   B         NaN
4   C         NaN
5   A         3
```

Currently I am able to do this with

```
df['value'] = pd.nan
df.loc[df.category == "A", ['value']] = range(1, len(df[df.category == "A"]) + 1)
```

Is there a better/pythonic way to do this (i.e. I don't have to initialize the value column with nan? And currently, this method assigns me a float type instead of integer which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Column `value` is not necessary inicialize if default values is `NaN`, if create without `[]`, also for count values of mask is used `sum`:

```
m = df.category == "A"
df.loc[m, 'value'] = range(1, m.sum() + 1)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype('Int64')

print (df)

0   1        A      1
1   2        A      2
2   3        B   <NA>
3   4        C   <NA>
4   5        A      3
```

If need also set to nullable integers:

```
m = df.category == "A"
df['value'] = m.cumsum().where(m).astype('Int64')
print (df)
   id category  value
0   1        A      1
1   2        A      2
2   3        B   <NA>
3   4        C   <NA>
4   5        A      3
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign it with integer instead of float data type? or is it like an additional line to convert the value column to integer?

Comment: @skinnyas123 - I think simpliest is convert to nullable integer after my solution, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) like `df['value'] = df['value'].astype('Int64')`

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
df['value'] = df['category'].eq('A').cumsum()
df['value'][df['category']!='A'] = pd.NA
```